# Solutions of recurrence relations $T(n) = 2T(n-1)$ and $T(n) = 2T(n-1) - 1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, computer-science, computational-complexity, substitution

> Consider the recurrence equation
>
> ```
> T(n) = 2T(n-1), if n>0
>      = 1, otherwise
> ```
>
> Then T(n) is (in big O order)
>
> ```
> (A) O(n)
> (B) O(2^n)
> (C) O(1)
> (D) O(log n)
> ```

#### My Try:

This has [already asked here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1286118/solving-tn-2tn-1) but there is no explanation.
Using Substitution Method:
$$T(n) = 2T(n−1)$$
$$= 2(2T(n−2)) = 2^2T(n-2)$$
$$= 2(2^2T(n−2)) = 2^3T(n-3)$$
$$....$$
$$= 2(2^{n-3}T(n−(n-2))) = 2^{n-2}T(n-(n-2))$$
$$= 2(2^{n-2}T(n−(n-1))) = 2^{n-1}T(n-(n-1)) = 2^{n-1}T(1) $$
$$= 2(2^{n-1}T(n−(n))) = 2^{n}T(n-(n)) = 2^{n}T(0) $$
$$T(n) = O(2^n)$$

This was from ISRO 2017 exam and official answer key is $O(1)$.

> So, my question is that if there is two function calls with each $(n-1)$ each time, then how it can be $O(1)$?

---

> There is another recurrence relation with little modification:
>
> ```
>  T(n) = 2T(n-1) - 1, if n>0
>       = 1, otherwise
> ```

AFAIK, it should be $O(2^n)$ again, but someone it explained as:

$$T(0) = 1 $$
$$T(1) = 2T(0)−1 = 1$$
$$T(2) = 2T(1)−1 = 1$$
$$T(3) = 2T(2)−1 = 1$$
$$T(4) = 2T(3)−1 = 1$$
$$...$$
So,  $T(n) = 1$, for any value of n i.e. it remains constant. Time Complexity $= O(1)$.

I agreed with calculated values (but it should be $O(2^n)$ [similar with this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1157319/solve-recurrence-equation-tn-2tn-1-4)).

> Is there any difference between values and complexity?

If above logic will applied then $T(n) = 2T(n-1)$ will be $O(1)$, also $T(n) = 2T(n/2)$ will be $O(1)$ which is NOT correct, because it should be $O(n)$ according to Master theorem.

> Could you please explain it?

Comment: Shouldn't arithmetic operations be constant time? I suppose it's a matter of perspective. Relative to more costly operations, one would consider arithmetic operations constant time. But the question only involves arithmetic operations. I am not a CS person. I wonder what the convention.

Comment: @Argyll, yes. arithmetic operations should be constant time but  $-1$ or $+1$ can affect values *not complexity*.

Comment: well, was the question asking for value in big O or complexity in big O?

Comment: Check: [Fibonacci](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/681524/how-to-go-about-solving-this-recurrence-relation)  and [Tower of Hanoi](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581236/concrete-mathematics-towers-of-hanoi-recurrence-relation) .

Comment: @Argyll, generally, they ask for _complexity_.

Comment: Doesnt that answer the question? If you consider all arithmetic operations as $O(n)$, I see the complexity of $T(n)$ as $O(T(0))$. Similarly $T(0)$ is considered as $O(0)$. I don't see why $O(T(n))$ wouldn't be $O(0)$.

Comment: correction all arithmetic operations as $O(0)$

Comment: @Argyll: arithmetic operations take constant time, but not zero time. In any case, they are asking for a big O estimate of $T$ in the question.  Typically, in applications, $T$ would measure the complexity of some function, so we look at a big O estimate for $T$ itself.

Comment: Another flaw in the question is that $O(1) \subseteq O(\log n) \subseteq O(n) \subseteq O(2^n)$, so if any answer is correct then so is $O(2^n)$. Now they might have put in the instructions to select the "best" answer, which would mean there is only one correct answer, but without that extra instruction there could be more than one correct answer.

Comment: @Carl, I agreed with you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $T(n) = 2T(n-1)$, $T(0) = 1$, the only solution is $T(n) = 2^n$, as you can check. That function is not $O(1)$, so there may be an error in the answer key.

For $T(n) = 2T(n-1) -1$, $T(0) = 1$, as you noticed the only solution is $T(n) = 1$. A recurrence like that has only one solution. Now $T(n) = 1$ is both $O(1)$ and $O(2^n)$.   This example is a kind of pathological case. If $T(0)$ was anything larger than $1$ the result would no longer be $O(1)$, but the result would still be $O(2^n)$.

Remember that $f(n) \in O(g(n))$ if there is a a $C$ so that $f(n) \leq Cg(n)$.  So if $f \in O(g)$ and $g \in O(h)$ then $f \in O(h)$ as well. So, in general, big O notation only gives an upper bound, not necessarily the best upper bound.

Comment: Thanks, but how you solve to $T(n)=2T(n−1)−1  = O(1)$, any hint, please? AFAIK, it should be $O(2^n)$, I refer [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1157319/solve-recurrence-equation-tn-2tn-1-4).

Comment: As I said, it depends on the initial condition. I solved both of these by guess and check.